# Points resulting from the intersection between three spheres using GPU hardware

Tags: opengl, cuda, geometry, gpu, hardware

There are analytical expressions that permit the calculation of the curve resulting from the overlapping between three penetrating spheres. There are also approximate methods that using grids or another methodologies, calculate points with more or less accuracy that belong to this interesection. I wonder if for the latter, the calculation can be done somehow using special hardware functions from the GPU, with CUDA or OpenGL. I need it for a very computing intensive number crunching program, so trivial implementations are not valid since they are very slow, and that is why I consider the GPU option

Comment: If you're intersecting spheres only, then the computation and the result trivial: The intersection of two spheres is always a circle or a point or nothing at all. --- The really hard stuff is intersections of parametric patch surfaces, as this is means finding the zero crossings for a high order polynomoial.

Comment: I mean three spheres; parametric patch surfaces, exactly

Comment: You may mix as many sphere's as you like, it's always almost trivial and very quick to solve. Intersecting three spheres ending up with two circular boundaries? No problem: Find the closest point (can be done analytical again) then use the turning angle on the circles as the first parameter and the circular arc between the points there, as the second parameter. Add another sphere and you interpolate between those arcs. The whole thing can be written in closed form in a recursive program. Exercise for the reader: Implement it in the functional language of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if a point (x, y, z) is in a sphere centered on (a, b, c) with radius r, the test is:

`(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 < r^2`

Testing if the point is in multiple spheres is just an `and` of similar expressions.  This only requires subtraction, multiplication, and comparison, no special hardware functions needed.  You can write a CUDA kernel that does this with no problem.

The closest "specialized hardware" that might be applicable is the `rsqrtf()` function in CUDA, which computes 1/sqrt(x) in single precision to good accuracy with a single hardware instruction.  You might use this to help calculate z values given x and y values of spheres, this could be useful for more sophisticated point generation algorithms for this problem.